# Express Sessions and Requests

Tags: node.js, express, angular, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using express for my backend in a web application. I've tested it extensively, and when logging in from localhost:3000, the session is saved and all other requests have a user object attached to them. I protected all routes to need a logged in user, and when checking those routes from localhost:3000 as an origin they all work. I also have a route, /api/users/auth, that returns if a user is authenticated or not.

My front end is an Angular 2 app. In development, it runs on localhost:8000. I can successfully post to the login route on my express server, localhost:3000/login, and it successfully logs in and returns the user. However, when I then try and access any other route or the /api/users/auth route, it says I'm not authorized. I also tried printing the request.user from the server when I make a call to a route, and it says it's undefined.

My question is: how do I make sure that the session is saved when I login from localhost:8000, or how do send the user that's returned from logging in as part of the request? It seems to be automatic on the localhost:3000 side.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using cookies?

Comment: Not on the Angular side. On the express side, I have cookie-parser and express-session that I'm using, but I haven't done much with them; just the default. Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/pjlamb12/ward-mission

Comment: So the session will create a cookie on the clinet side, I remember taht you can get the session id from that cookie, and with taht you can know if the session its initiated, I think that you can also set cookies form the server.

I will take a look at your repo tomorrow.

I reccomen you to do some research about the cookies and accesing them on the client and how to set cookies form the server using nodejs. Im sure you will find a solution there.

Comment: I read about `express-session`, and what I did didn't seem to help much. In the login function, I saved the user to the req.session, but then on the next check it gave me nothing back for that user being on the req.session. Again, when I use Postman and am checking this all originating from localhost:3000, then it saves the session and I have no issues. Just from the client side, localhost:8000.